# Is it advisable to publish in low tier conferences as an undergrad?

Tags: publications, thesis, conference

I am currently an undergrad and worked on a project that might get published in a low tier conference. I currently have 0 publications but this work is not something I'm proud of. Is it advisable to have my name on this paper given that I am currently working on other projects that can potentially get published at much better conferences? My only concern is that it might negatively impact my profile in the long term. I plan on pursuing a thesis based MS/ PhD after my undergrad. The domain is Computer Architecture if that's relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of not well-reputed conferences, you can submit to workshops held at good conferences or in late-breaking tracks.

The difference, in my opinion, is that in low-level conferences, low-quality papers (e.g. not well written, fundamentally wrong, etc) can be accepted and sometimes without being reviewed. However, for good workshops, you will still need to write a good paper with an idea built on a good basis. They expect, however, that the experiments and results are not strong enough or the approach is not sophisticated to a point that allows it to be published at a good conference.

In summary, a paper at a good workshop demonstrates that the paper fulfils the necessary academic conditions, while a paper at a bad conference does not.

Answering your question, Yes, having a paper at a low-level conference might hurt your profile or at least it won't help at all.

Comment: +1. Besides workshops in top-tier conferences, I would say specialised conferences classified as low tier (say a core ranking of B), still attract many good people. What is a complete waste of time in my opinion is general CS/AI  low tier conferences.